# How check if my previous activity exist?

Tags: android, android-activity

In my app, there are 3 activities and their calling sequence is like this...

Splash activity--->Dashboard Activity--->List Activity

If it goes like this then If I press back button on List activity then it will follow the reverse sequence of above.

There is one requirement where user can navigate to List Activity directly from Splash (Skipping Dashboard Activity) Now when user will hit back button on List Activity then I wan't to show Dashboard Activity which is not there in the Activity Stack.

So please help me with the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a boolean through the intent for going to List Activity from either of the others. Using `onBackPressed` check if the boolean is true or false for skipping Dashboard Activity.
Then if true put new intent for loading dashboard activity and finish(); on list activity.

Comment: Is passing true or false in the intent extra will give proper understanding in future?

Comment: If the commenting is up to scratch then sure.

Answer (score 0):

you can directly go to splash from list Activity while going to

`ListActivity` from `Dashboard Activity` call `finish()`

```
Intent i = new Intent(DashboardActivity.this,ListActivity);
startActivtiy(i);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass class name as intent extra from both Splash and DashboardActiviy.

In List Activity you have to get the class name using getIntent().

When the user click back button, you need to check the class name based on that you can take decision.

```
    if(name.equalIgnorecase(DashboardActivit.class.getSimpleName()){
      //Add your intent
    }else{
      //
    }
```

This may give you definite solution to you.Give a try

Answer (score 0):

Start your inner activities with `startAcvitiyForResult`

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity_2.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

and in your inner activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed ()
{
    finish();
}
```

You can also do stuff in your outer activity as you like after your inner activity finishes

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == 1){
            Log.i("TEST", "RESULT_OK");
        }
        else {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```